# Are penguins plantigrade or digigrade?

Tags: zoology

I'm trying to rig a 3D model of a penguin, but I don't know where to put the bones near the ankle because I can't tell if they're digigrade or plantigrade. Nearly all birds are digigrade, but penguins spend a lot of time walking and don't generally grasp or run with their talons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plantigrade.

> The penguins are highly specialized for their flightless aquatic
>   existence. The feet are located much farther back than those of other
>   birds, with the result that the bird carries itself mostly upright;
>   its walk can thus be described as plantigrade (i.e., on the soles).
>   The sole comprises the whole foot instead of just the toes, as in
>   other birds. The most notable characteristic of the group is the
>   transformation of the forelimb into a paddle. This is accompanied by a
>   body morphology particularly adapted to movement in a liquid medium.
>   The thoracic (rib) cage is well developed, and the sternum bears a
>   pronounced keel for the attachment of the pectoral muscles, which move
>   the flippers. The flipper has the same skeletal base as the wing of
>   flying birds but with its elements shortened and flattened, producing
>   a relatively rigid limb covered with very short feathers—an ideal
>   organ for rapid propulsion. The body plumage likewise consists of very
>   short feathers, which minimize friction and turbulence. The density of
>   the plumage and the layer of air that it retains provide almost
>   complete insulation of the body.

https://www.britannica.com/animal/penguin#ref3467
[image]